# How do I create shortcut icons to the desktop?

Tags: shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

If I right click on the desktop, I don't see that option.

Where can I create shortcut icons?